# TikZ - multi-color double circle node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, circles

How do I draw a node with a double circle shape where one circle has a different color than the other circle?

[image: multicolor node with doublecircle style]

A single `\node[whatever] {content}` would be nice!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) What exactly do you mean by "double circle shape"? Can you show a picture, perhaps?

Comment: thanks! could you re-edit to make the picture inline? i can't do it since i've <10 reputation

Comment: Done. You can use backticks (`\``) to mark inline code, as I did in my edit. Or, select the code and hit Ctrl + K.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's a new style `double circle` that can be supplied to a node. It takes two arguments, one for specifying how much larger the radius of the outer circle is (default is `2pt`), and the second for specifying the colour (or any combination of options, really) of the inner circle (default is `blue`).

If you specify a node name, this will refer to the outer node (thanks to Andrew Stacey for the suggestion).

```
\node (A) [double circle, draw=red] {b};
\node (B) at (2,0) [draw, double circle={-2pt}{orange}] {ABC};
\draw (A) -- (B);
```

will give you

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm] {standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    old inner xsep/.estore in=\oldinnerxsep,
    old inner ysep/.estore in=\oldinnerysep,
    double circle/.style 2 args={
        circle,
        old inner xsep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
        old inner ysep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep},
        /pgf/inner xsep=\oldinnerxsep+#1,
        /pgf/inner ysep=\oldinnerysep+#1,
        alias=sourcenode,
        append after command={
        let     \p1 = (sourcenode.center),
                \p2 = (sourcenode.east),
                \n1 = {\x2-\x1-#1-0.5*\pgflinewidth}
        in
            node [inner sep=0pt, draw, circle, minimum width=2*\n1,at=(\p1),#2] {}
        }
    },
    double circle/.default={2pt}{blue}
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) [double circle, draw=red] {b};
\node (B) at (2,0) [draw, double circle={-2pt}{orange}] {ABC};
\draw (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}%
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would make the *outer* circle the one drawn by the node (at least by default) and increase the `inner sep` to ensure that there is room for the inner circle.  My reason for this is that with a double circle I would expect the node boundary to be on the outer circle, not the inner one.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: The first argument can be negative though. So depending on the input which circle is the outer one may vary. I do agree that by default a positive value should give the expected behaviour, which I would also expect to be the outer circle as the node boundary.

Comment: @wh1t3 Yes, I see that.  My comment is all about polishing and nothing about *substance*.  It's a nice solution (particularly as it doesn't involve defining a new node shape) and this is purely about what a user might expect the default action to be.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Good point! Unfortunately, the value of `inner sep` can't simply be accessed using `\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inner sep}`, so making this solution behave as you suggest isn't trivial. Feel free to edit this answer or add a new one if you come up with a way to make the outer circle the node border.

Comment: Looking at the code, it should be the value of `/pgf/inner xsep` (and `/pgf/inner ysep`).  I haven't tested it, though.

Answer (score 20):

Not sure exactly what you want, but here are five different ways:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Version 1
\draw [red ] (0,0) circle (5pt);
\draw [blue] (0,0) circle (10pt);
\node at     (0,0) {1};

% Version 2
\node [draw=blue,double=red, circle, inner sep=1pt] at (1,0) {2};

% Version 3
\draw [draw=red, inner sep=1pt]  (2,0) circle (8pt);
\node [draw=blue, circle, inner sep=1pt] at (2,0) {3};

% Version 4
\path (3,0) node [draw=red,shape=circle]  {}
      (3,0) node [draw=blue,shape=circle] {4};

% Version 5 (similar to Version 2)
\path (4,0) node [draw=blue, shape=circle, double=red] {5};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If not, replace `draw` commands with `\fill [blue] (0,0) circle (10pt);\fill [red ] (0,0) circle (5pt);`.

Comment: thanks! is there a way to have a single \node[whatever] {content}?

Comment: See updated solution. Is Version 2 or 5 what you want?

Comment: i would like the stroke to have a different color and both circle having slightly different size, so version 3 would be the closest one. thanks for all the nice tikz snippets

Answer (score 2):

great job, I used your code to start a vertical timeline..

```
\usetikzlibrary[calc,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri,shapes,mindmap,shadows]

\tikzset{
    old inner xsep/.estore in=\oldinnerxsep,
    old inner ysep/.estore in=\oldinnerysep,
    double circle/.style 2 args={
        circle,
        old inner xsep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
        old inner ysep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep},
        /pgf/inner xsep=\oldinnerxsep+#1,
        /pgf/inner ysep=\oldinnerysep+#1,
        alias=sourcenode,
        append after command={
        let     \p1 = (sourcenode.center),
                \p2 = (sourcenode.east),
                \n1 = {\x2-\x1-#1-0.8*\pgflinewidth}
        in
            node [inner sep=0.01pt, draw,circle, fill, minimum width=1*\n1,at=(\p1),#2] {}
        }
    },
    double circle/.default={2.5pt}{blue!50}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
nonterminal/.style={rectangle,minimum size=6mm,very thick,draw=red!50!black!50,top color=white, bottom color=red!50!black!20,font=\itshape},
%{ The shape:, The size:, The border:, 50 % red and 50% black, and that mixed with 50% white,  The filling:, a shading that is white at the top...,and something else at the bottom, Font}
terminal/.style={rectangle,minimum size=6mm,rounded corners=3mm,very thick,draw=black!50,top color=white,bottom color=black!20,font=\ttfamily},
line width=4pt,
circulo/.style={circle,minimum size=3mm,line cap=rect,draw=blue!50,top color=white,bottom color=blue!40,font=\ttfamily}
]
\node (A) [double circle, draw=blue!20] {};
\node (B) [double circle, draw=blue!20][below=of A] {};
\node (C) [double circle, draw=blue!20][below=of B] {};
\node (D) [double circle, draw=blue!20][below=of C] {};
\node (E) [double circle, draw=blue!20][below=of D] {};
\node (F) [double circle, draw=blue!20][below=of E] {};
\node (G) [double circle, draw=blue!20][below=of F] {};
\node (H) [double circle, draw=blue!20][below=of G] {};
\draw[-] [blue!20] (A) -- (H);
\node (B1) [rectangle, minimum size = 6mm][below=of A,label=right:Primeira Etapa, label=left:2008] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Note that this is a Question and Answer (or Q&A) site and not a forum that hosts discussions on a specific topic. Even though this is a neat application of an answer for the given question, it is technically not an "answer".