# Decorate path with just a colored thick line

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to decorate a path with just a thick colored line above or below it? In the following example I faked manually the result, but how can I do it with decorations? In particular I want to be able to choose the color and the line width and use the raise option of the decoration.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
   \coordinate (B) at (1,1);
   \coordinate (v) at ($(B) - (A)$);

   \path let \p1 = (v) in ($1/(\x1^2 + \y1^2)^(0.5)*(\y1,-\x1)$) coordinate (p);
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\dist}{0.7}
   \coordinate (AA) at ($(A) + \dist*(p)$);
   \coordinate (BB) at ($(B) + \dist*(p)$);

   \draw (A) -- (B);
   \draw[thick,orange] (AA) -- (BB);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**Edit:** If it is not possible to get it via decorations is it possible to define a style just for straight lines which allows you to draw two or three colored lines just like here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36858/4011 in the case of circles.

Comment: Do you want this to work with curves and polygons, or just with straight lines?

Comment: For my current application I want it only for straight lines.

Comment: But if it is possible to do it with decorations, then it should automatically work with arbitrary path's...?

Comment: Take a look at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29991/86 Is that the sort of thing you are after?

Comment: @AndrewStacey Thanks, but I think this doesn't really help. I want to know how to do it with decorations and the inside-outside problem doesn't matter in my case...

Comment: @student: Well, for a straight line the decoration doesn't have to be very smart, as it's sufficient to just shift each coordinate by a fixed amount. With polygons, this is more difficult as the shift amount would depend on the angles of the corners, and with curves you'd need to introduce a number of support points.

Comment: There's also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31707/86

Comment: @Jake for my problem it would be enough to have it for straight lines. But is should work well with the shorten option.

Answer (score 2):

Will using `double` help here?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
   \coordinate (B) at (1,1);
   \coordinate (v) at ($(B) - (A)$);

   \path let \p1 = (v) in ($1/(\x1^2 + \y1^2)^(0.5)*(\y1,-\x1)$) coordinate (p);
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\dist}{0.7}
   \coordinate (AA) at ($(A) + \dist*(p)$);
   \coordinate (BB) at ($(B) + \dist*(p)$); 
   \draw[line width=5pt,orange,double=black,double distance=1pt] (AA) -- (BB);

   \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
   \draw[very thick, orange,double=black,double distance=1pt] (-0.1,5) .. controls (-4,-2) and (4,-2) .. (0.1,5);
   \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The problem with double is that then I get the colored line on both sides.