# How to create a doublecircle in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to create a circle in circle (doublecircle) style like this:
[image].

```
\tikzset{
    place/.style={
        circle,
        thick,
        draw=black!75,
        fill=white!20,
        minimum size=6mm,
    }
}
```

as shown in tikz [docs](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/nodetutorial/)

Update in response to comments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,shapes,automata,petri,positioning}
\tikzset{
    old inner xsep/.estore in=\oldinnerxsep,
    old inner ysep/.estore in=\oldinnerysep,
    double circle/.style 2 args={
        circle,
        old inner xsep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
        old inner ysep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep},
        /pgf/inner xsep=\oldinnerxsep+#1,
        /pgf/inner ysep=\oldinnerysep+#1,
        alias=sourcenode,
        append after command={
        let     \p1 = (sourcenode.center),
                \p2 = (sourcenode.east),
                \n1 = {\x2-\x1-#1-0.5*\pgflinewidth}
        in
            node [inner sep=0pt, draw, circle, minimum width=2*\n1,at=(\p1),#2] {}
        }
    },
    double circle/.default={2pt}{blue},
    place/.style={
        double circle,
        thick,
        draw=black!75,
        %fill=white!20,
        minimum size=6mm,
    },
    transitionH/.style={
        rectangle,
        thick,
        fill=black,
        minimum width=8mm,
        inner ysep=2pt
    },
    transitionV/.style={
        rectangle,
        thick,
        fill=black,
        minimum height=8mm,
        inner xsep=2pt
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.4cm and 1cm,>=stealth',bend angle=45,auto]
    \node [place,label=above:$P_1$] (p1) {}
    \node [transitionV,label=above:$T_1$] (t1) [right= of p1] {}
        edge[pre]   (p1);
    \node [place,tokens=1,label=above:$P_2$] (p2) [above right=of t1] {}
        edge[pre]   (t1);
    \node [place,tokens=2,label=above:$P_3$] (p3) [below right=of t1] {}
        edge[pre]   (t1);
    \node [transitionV,label=above:$T_2$] (t2) [above right=of p3] {}
        edge[pre]   (p2)
        edge[pre]   (p3);
    \node [place,tokens=1, label=above:$P_4$] (p4) [above right=of t2] {}
        edge[pre]   (t2);
   \draw[post] (t2.east)  to[out=-30,in=210,overlay,looseness=2.3] (p1); 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  Does [TikZ - multi-color double circle node](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36856/tikz-multi-color-double-circle-node) answer your question? While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Just adding `double` and specifying a non-white `fill` seems to work just fine.

Comment: @Peter Grill: if I add no code from provided link I get: `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/double circle' and I am g
oing to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.` If I add code from answer I get `! Package pgf Error: No shape named  is known.` error (added code to question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the options `double` to the `place` style and changing the fill color to a non-white color yields the desired results:

[image]

---

Your full code has a lot of other stuff then what should be in a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). 
  In your full code you were missing a comm and a semi-colon - thing totally unrelated to drawing a double circle. This is one of the reasons to keep the same code to a minimum so we can focus on the actual issue.

After fixing those the code produces:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    place/.style={
        circle, double,
        thick,
        draw=black!75,
        fill=gray!20,
        minimum size=6mm,
    }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[place] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,shapes,automata,petri,positioning}
\tikzset{
    old inner xsep/.estore in=\oldinnerxsep,
    old inner ysep/.estore in=\oldinnerysep,
    double circle/.style 2 args={
        circle,
        old inner xsep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
        old inner ysep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep},
        /pgf/inner xsep=\oldinnerxsep+#1,
        /pgf/inner ysep=\oldinnerysep+#1,
        alias=sourcenode,
        append after command={
        let     \p1 = (sourcenode.center),
                \p2 = (sourcenode.east),
                \n1 = {\x2-\x1-#1-0.5*\pgflinewidth}
        in
            node [inner sep=0pt, draw, circle, minimum width=2*\n1,at=(\p1),#2] {}
        }
    },
    double circle/.default={2pt}{blue},
    place/.style={
        double, circle,% <--- missing comma
        thick,
        draw=black!75,
        %fill=white!20,
        minimum size=6mm,
    },
    transitionH/.style={
        rectangle,
        thick,
        fill=black,
        minimum width=8mm,
        inner ysep=2pt
    },
    transitionV/.style={
        rectangle,
        thick,
        fill=black,
        minimum height=8mm,
        inner xsep=2pt
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.4cm and 1cm,>=stealth',bend angle=45,auto]
    \node [place,label=above:$P_1$] (p1) {};% <---- Missing semi colon
    \node [transitionV,label=above:$T_1$] (t1) [right= of p1] {}
        edge[pre]   (p1);
    \node [place,tokens=1,label=above:$P_2$] (p2) [above right=of t1] {}
        edge[pre]   (t1);
    \node [place,tokens=2,label=above:$P_3$] (p3) [below right=of t1] {}
        edge[pre]   (t1);
    \node [transitionV,label=above:$T_2$] (t2) [above right=of p3] {}
        edge[pre]   (p2)
        edge[pre]   (p3);
    \node [place,tokens=1, label=above:$P_4$] (p4) [above right=of t2] {}
        edge[pre]   (t2);
   \draw[post] (t2.east)  to[out=-30,in=210,overlay,looseness=2.3] (p1); 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```